# Can't get new items to save to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ugh please help.... I'm new to Swift (coding in general) however I used this same code to make an earlier app that had  a VC with 1 text field, a rating control and an image and worked fine.  This version has 2 text fields and a date picker but only the sample data appears in the tableView when trying to add an new item.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUVPs.jpg)
So here after clicking the + button you're taken to the next page where you can add new information (below) upon pressing save the new information should appear in the starting tableview.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GKdU.png)

import UIKit

class BudgetTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
//Properties
var budgets = [Budget]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadSampleBudgets()

}

func loadSampleBudgets() {

    let budget1 = Budget(date: "8/16/2016", name: "Eyebrows", amount: "15")!
    let budget2 = Budget(date: "8/28/2016", name: "Acme", amount: "59")!
    let budget3 = Budget(date: "9/10/2016", name: "Wildwood", amount: "199")!

    budgets += [budget1, budget2, budget3]
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return budgets.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "BudgetTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BudgetTableViewCell
    let budget = budgets[indexPath.row]

    cell.dateLabel.text = budget.date
    cell.nameLabel.text = budget.name
    cell.amountLabel.text = budget.amount
    return cell
}

@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? BudgetViewController, budget = sourceViewController.budget {
        //Add a new meal
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: budgets.count, inSection: 0)
        budgets.append(budget)
    }
}
```

> > > > > > break second VC

import UIKit

class BudgetViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
// Properties:
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!


var budget: Budget?

// Date picker:
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

func setDate() {
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateDisplay.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
}

// Navigation

// This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {

        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let date = dateDisplay.text ?? ""
        let amount = amountTextField.text ?? ""

// set the budget to be passed to the Controller, this code configures the meal prperty with the appropriate values before the segue executes

        budget = Budget(date: date, name: name, amount: amount)

    }
}

// Actions:
@IBAction func datePickerChanger(sender: AnyObject) {
    setDate()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field

    nameTextField.delegate = self
    amountTextField.delegate = self
}
// UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {


}
```

}

Comment: could you please update screenshot accordingly and explain it little bit more   to understand where item not added

Comment: You need to reloadData() on your TableView after adding new data to its DataSource, or did I just not see it? :-)

Comment: Could you Upload your Project to GIT, or send it to me via email?

Comment: I can email it to you @Neo... now I have realize that the issue was that I cannot assign  2 different textfields as the delegate... at least not in the manner I did it.  So I deleted the "amountTextField" everywhere and added insertRowsAtIndexPaths and it works.  But I need 2 (possible 3) textfields, so how do I add them.  I'm thinking there must be a way to put them in an order, but have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` or `reloadData` method for update table view after adding new data to budgets(table view's data source)

Comment: Thanks @GarveyCalvin so I added insertRowsAtIndexPaths but it still wasnt working.  I realized it's from having 2 textfields assigned as the delegate. once I deleted one (and all properties) it worked.  But I need 2 (really 3)... so how do you use more than 1 textfield in the same viewcontroller?

Comment: Well, I don´t think that you understood the delegate pattern the way it should be used... If you understand it, it will help you understanding a lot of things... if you have further questions dennis.weidmann@gmx.de